# Merge text in a single column

Tags: sql, hana

I have a table, sample records are shown below -

```
Name       ID      C.NO   Text
----       ----    ----   ----
ABC        A       1      first
ABC        A       2      xyz
ABC        A       3      AMD
ZSD        B       1      hoho
ZSD        B       2      hihi
```

now my output would be like -------

```
Name      ID      Text
----      ---     ----
ABC       A       firstxyzAMD
ZSD       B       hohohihi
```

kindly help me providing sql statement

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  I am guessing that "Hana" is the right tag, because it was the last one added.

Comment: using HANA, thanks, it's working

Answer (score 3):

In SAP Hana, you would use `string_agg()`:

```
select name, id, string_agg(text, '')
from t
group by name, id;
```

The equivalent function in MySQL is `group_concat()`; in Oracle, `listagg()`.

Comment: I am using HANA Db , so I have to find the appropriate function, thanks.. string_agg(text, '') is there

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT
   GROUP_CONCAT(`text`, '' SEPARATOR '') AS `newtext`
FROM [table]
GROUP BY `name`;
```

Comment: You can use `GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR "")`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, following query worked in my table (MySQL) and I got the exact result as per your specification

```
select 
    Name,
    ID,
    group_concat(Text SEPARATOR '')
from table_name
group by ID
```